# How can I make this array with data from a database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

How can I make this array with data from a database?

```
$array=array("a"=>"Apple","b"=>"Ball","c"=>"Cat");
```

I have a database table with column `letter` and `value`.

```
letter | value
       |
  a    | Apple
  b    | Ball
  c    | Cat
```

I want `"a"=>"Apple","b"=>"Ball","c"=>"Cat"` to be values from the database, using for loop, how is that possible?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: first question, what database?

Comment: thanks for your response @Dagon, its MySql..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

assuming you can do the connection and select

```
$array=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[$row['letter']]=$row['value'];
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Wow! I got the idea from your answer, thanks @Dagon! I just made a little modification based on my needs:

`$options=array();
foreach ($products as $key => $value){
 $options[$value]=$value;
}`

Comment: your code does no make much sense related to the question above, your just reformatting an existing array taking the values from one to make another with matching key values pairs, which is a little pointless